# Entity Framework sets foreign key to null during saving

Tags: entity-framework, null, save

I have workflow like this:

```
using dataContext
{
  load entity
  int? previousFr = entity.FrSomething
  entity.FrSomething = null               
  entity.FrSomething = previousFr         
  save entity
}
```

during save entity.FrSomething becomes null and null value is saved to database

this is call stack between dataContext.SaveChanges() and FrSomething property setter
[image]

UPD: It's Entity framework 4, self-tracking template. I have entity Product and combobox with product Categories. I load Product for edit and list of Categories to fill combo. Product initially has some category specified, and corresponding navigation property is set during EF fixup. Then I select none-category in combobox (FrCategory = null), then select previous one which product had initially. If after selecting none category I select other then initial one, issue is not reproduced. if I change category with Product.Category property instead of Product.FrCategory, issue is not reproduced as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but I cannot replicate the issue. You may want to share your model and mapping. Specify which version of EF you work on.

Comment: It's Entity framework 4

Comment: It's Entity framework 4. I have entity Product and combobox with product Categories. I load Product for edit and list of Categories to fill combo. Product initially has some category specified, and corresponding navigation property is set during EF fixup. Then I select none-category in combobox (FrCategory = null), then select previous one which product had initially. If after selecting none category I select other then initial one, issue is not reproduced. if I change category with Product.Category property instead of Product.FrCategory, issue is not reproduced as well.

Comment: int? previous = job.MapId;
            job.MapId = null;
            job.MapId = previous;

            _unitOfWork.Save(); This works for me.

Comment: What is value of corresponding navigation property job.Map? In my case it's not null, may be, the source of problem is here.

Comment: It is not null, because fixup kicks in when you save. So after second line job.mapid=null, job.map=proxy. If I saved now, the fix-up would kick in and set Map to null, but I don't. In the third line I restore they key back to original value. So when I save, no fix-up actually happens. Unless you use change tracking proxies, then it would fix up immediately.